# DLL Build Error related to string type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

3I'm learning how to use C++ to write DLLs and am following [this tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3WWA8eEX9Q) to get me started. I follow along exactly, my code being:

defFile.def:

```
LIBRARY "square"
EXPORTS 
square
```

funct.cpp:

```
double __stdcall square(double & x) 
{
    return x*x;
}
```

When trying to Build using VSE 2010, I get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: square, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  defFile.def
1>c:\documents and settings\~\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\square\square\deffile.def(2): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'string'
1>c:\documents and settings\~\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\square\square\deffile.def(2): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've tried adding `#include <string>` at the top of defFile.def, but still get the same error. I'm sure this is something really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the .def file to your project.  It is getting compiled as though it is a source code file.  That can't work.

Right-click your project, Properties, Linker, Input.  Set the Module Definition File setting to "defFile.def".

Comment: Being new to C++, I used F7 to Build, when I should have used Ctrl+F7. This compiled, but still didn't build the DLL. I had to right-click on the defFile and "Exclude from Project."

Answer (score 0):

Definition file is not C++. Remove `using namespace std;` from there. Also, you're not supposed to compile it, if you want to use it, you need to modify linker settings for the project.

Comment: Sorry, it was suggested in another Stack Overflow question and was trying to use that to solve my problem. I receive the same error when that is removed. I've updated the question to reflect the original issue as it was.

Comment: Do you mean adding defFile.def to the Module Definition File setting? I've done that. And my understanding is that I will have to compile/build the project to make a compiled DLL file?

Comment: @Alec: Don't compile the .def file. It's not a source file.